# Removing unwanted characters in an organic molecule diagram

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, image-segmentation

I have this image:

[image]

I want to remove all the parts of the image which do not form part of the organic molecule structure. So in this particular image, I want to remove `Process A` and the `line below it`. I tried to use `bwlabel` to get connected components but the structure itself does not form one single component. As such, removal by that method is not possible. Any idea how I can go about this problem?

Comment: The question may sound stupid, but what is the difference between the parts you want and the parts you don't want? Both are lines and chars. Maybe detect the vertical gap (use row sum) and split there? Maybe use imerode to connect both black areas, then segment with bwlabel?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two ways you can approach this, depending on your preference.

## Method #1 - Using `bwareaopen`

A cheap way to do this would be to invert the image so that the object pixels are white instead of black, then performing a morphological closing on the image and removing those areas that fall under a certain amount.  Closing would join disconnected regions together and taking advantage that joining the "structure" would generate a region with a large area, you can threshold by the area of each region and eliminate those regions that fall below a certain amount.

You can then get back the original image by simply performing a logical `AND` with the inverted image and the closed result, then reinverting this intermediate result.  The effect of this would be that we only keep the pixels that belong to the original image due to the closing operation artificially creating object pixels. Specifically, the joining of the nearby regions of the structure would create new object pixels and so performing an `AND` will ensure that those pixels not in common with the original get removed. As this is performed on the reverse of the original result, reinverting gets you back to the original domain of object pixels being black instead of white.

Something like this:

```
%// Read in image from StackOverflow
im = imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/A7iT7.png');

%// Invert image
im = ~im;

%// Define 50 x 50 structuring element and close the image
se = strel('square', 50);
out = imclose(im, se);

%// Remove regions whose areas fall below 10000 pixels
out = bwareaopen(out, 10000);

%// Remove out extraneous closing areas by ANDing with inverted image
%// then reinvert to bring back to original label scheme
out = ~(im & out);

%// Show the image
imshow(out);
```

We get this image:

[image]

## Notes

1. The function [`imclose`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imclose.html) will perform the morphological closing for you with a structuring element defined by [`strel`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/strel.html).  I used a 50 x 50 square to ensure that we have a large enough window to join neighbouring object pixels together.
2. The function [`bwareaopen`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwareaopen.html) takes in a binary image and removes out regions whose pixel areas fall below a certain amount.  After doing a closing, you will have two connected regions - the top of the image with the structure and the bottom with the text.  By experimentation, 10000 pixels removed the region at the bottom.

---

## Method #2 - Using `regionprops`

Related to Method #1, an alternative method to doing this and being threshold agnostic is to go with your original idea.  Do the closing operation, but then assess the areas of each of the connected regions and select the one with the largest area.  What I recommend is to use [`regionprops`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/regionprops.html) in that case, which is a function that is specifically designed to analyze characteristics of distinct image regions.  The output will be a structure of `N` elements, where `N` is the total number of unique and connected objects found in the image and each structure contains fields of properties you'd like to measure in the image.  In your case, specify the  `'Area'` and the `'PixelIdxList'` attributes which contain the areas and column-major pixel locations of each region.

You'd find the maximum area overall and use the corresponding pixel locations and set an output map which you'd logical `AND` with.

Something like this:

```
%// Read in image from StackOverflow
im = imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/A7iT7.png');

%// Invert image
im = ~im;

%// Define 50 x 50 structuring element and close the image
se = strel('square', 50);
out = imclose(im, se);

s = regionprops(out, 'Area', 'PixelIdxList'); %// Apply regionprops

%// Find the region with the max area
[~,id] = max([s.Area]);

%// Create an output mask with the largest area
%// Make logical
out = false(size(im));

%// Set pixels from largest area
out(s(id).PixelIdxList) = true;

%// Rest of the logic from before
%// Remove out extraneous closing areas by ANDing with inverted image
%// then reinvert to bring back to original label scheme
out = ~(im & out);

%// Show the image
imshow(out);
```

You should get exactly the same results as the first method.

Comment: Thanks a lot.I still have a question.By bwareapen you are removing regions whose pixel areas are below 1000. Is  there some way I can find the pixel-areas of every region after closing operation.This is because in most cases I require only the largest connected region,so if I could get the pixel areas of every connected region I could just take the one with the largest area

Comment: Ah yes you can. Give me a bit to modify my answer. To be honest, your idea was another I was considering but I wanted to get you an answer quickly.

Comment: In fact I tried using `bwlabel` after `closing` operation to get the connected component.Using first connected component then I got my original image by doing logical `AND`.It happens to give the correct result. But I dont think everytime the first component will be the one with largest area.That is why I wanted to get the areas of every region

Comment: Use `regionprops` with the Area and PixelIdxList attributes.

Comment: @Noober - Done. Have a look.

Answer (score 1):

Following the assumption that the image title is separated in space from the "actual image" far enough:

Construct blobs by blurring the image, find connected components, take the upper/bigger one (or some other heuristic that depends on your data). So, before using a connected component algorithm, perform preprocessing:

1. Gauss/Median Filter (if needed) and edge detection.
2. Binarization
3. Morphological operations (erosion, dilation)
4. Blob Extraction with heuristics (size/shape/position).

while 4. is a substitute for connected components (which is not mandatory). You can search for other methods under the keyword `blob extraction` or `text extraction`. This is a rough outline of what you would do "in the general case". Which steps bring the best solution is highly up to your data, so you'll have to experiment a bit.